# AngularJS ng-click can't call function from ctrl

Tags: html, angularjs

I made a route in my app, and I want to show alert when click button in template :

please help me:

this is my JavaScript:

```js
var trainingApp = angular.module('training', ['daypilot','ngRoute']);
```

```js
angular.module('training')



.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/login',{
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller:  'profilecontroller'
    })
})


.controller('profilecontroller',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.alertt = function(){

    alert("okkkkkkk");
}
}])

.controller('mainCtrl', .........
```

```html
<button  ng-click="alertt()">ok</button>
```

Comment: What does the routing system has to do with the `ng-click`here?

Comment: check wether your controller is correct or not..?

Comment: @lealceldeiro my app have two page index and login the button is in login.html ... when I write my url .../login the ng-click of the button can't call function alertt ..

Comment: I don't see any issues with this code, but you could try using controllerAs syntax

Comment: @Fredj create a fiddle or plunker